# How to find n most different paths in a graph?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I am using the *NetworkX* library for Python in my application that does some graph processing. One task is to call the `all_simple_paths()` function of *NetworkX* to give me all non-looping paths in the graph (up to a certain max. length of paths). This is working well.

Using this list of all simple paths in the graph the task is now to find a number of *n* paths out of this list, where each of these *n* paths should be as different from all other *n* paths as possible. Or in other words: any two paths from the resulting *n* paths should have as few common nodes as possible. Or in even other words: each path in the resulting *n* paths should be as unique as possible.

Can you guys think of any (non brute force) algorithm to achieve this?

Comment: Any two distinct edges have at most one vertex in common. Any two distinct paths consisting of two edges have at most two vertices in common. Work from there.

Comment: Maxflow allows you to find n paths where each node is used in at most k paths. That bounds the total, but not the maximum number of common nodes between two paths, maybe that's helpful

Comment: @G.Bach I don't see the usefulness of your observation

Comment: @NiklasB The shorter the paths, the fewer nodes they cover, i.e. the lower the maximum of shared nodes. Since the specs say that we can use all simple paths up to a fixed length, we can greedily use 1-edge paths first, then 2-edge paths, etc.

Comment: @G.Bach: Oh I see. I didn't think *enumerating all frigging paths* would be considered non-brute-force...

Comment: @NiklasB. For complete graphs, that's linear in n since the choice of paths doesn't matter after the first (number of vertices)/2 paths. For incomplete graphs, it's a bit trickier but should still be manageable. You basically start out with a maximum matching and keep adding stuff.

Comment: @G.Bach: What I'm trying to say is that you have an exponential amount of paths in general graphs, so it's typically not feasible to enumerate them all to compute some aggregation over them. But obviously it works for OP.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah sure, exponentially many in the number of vertices, but then again maybe so is n. I'm not sure whether your objection is to what I suggested or something else.

Comment: @G.Bach: any reasonable algorithm to solve a problem like this in polynomial time (which is probably impossible) would certainly not be based on a half-sentence observation. That's why I didn't even bother to think about what you said, to be honest ;)

Comment: @NiklasB. It would actually give you a polynomial time algorithm in the maximum of n and the number of vertices, since the bottleneck for small n will be finding the initial maximum matching, and the bottleneck for large n (as soon as n > m/2) will be the enumeration, which is linear in n.

Comment: @G.Bach: I don't see what algorithm you have in mind. In case that there are m = n vertex-disjoint paths in the graph, you would have to output those, so the problem is at least as hard as max-flow. How can there be an algorithm mightily enough to solve max-flow but "obvious" to understand from a comment like "Any two distinct edges have at most one vertex in common. Any two distinct paths consisting of two edges have at most two vertices in common. "?

Comment: @NiklasB. A maximum matching will contain at least n edges in that case. After you found that, you can greedily enumerate paths, since when adding distinct paths of length k + 1, they can overlap in at most k edges (i.e. k+1 vertices) and since you exhaust all paths of length k before adding those of length k + 1, you will have an overlap of k edges any way.

Comment: @G.Bach: Greedy will certainly not work. Say `n = 2`. If your greedy choice is bad, both path prefixes might end up in a subgraph where you have no choice but to overlap the rest of the way to the sink.

Comment: @NiklasB. I don't understand what you're saying. He's not asking for paths that overlap with as few other paths as possible, he's asking for paths that have minimum pairwise overlap. An initial greedy choice of a maximum matching ensures an initial maximum overlap of 0, then using all paths of length 1 (i.e. single edges) keeps the maximum overlap down to 1, after that paths of length 2 will keep the maximum overlap down to 2, etc.

Comment: @G.Bach: How does a matching induce a set of paths? Maybe that's what I'm not understanding. The thing is, since I already know that this problem is at least as hard as the "maximum number of vertex-disjoint paths" problem, I just don't see how that is solvable with a combination of maximum matching and greediness.

Comment: @NiklasB. A matching is a set of edges, i.e. a set of paths of length 1. Regarding the flows, I'm not sure. Could you link to something about that, is there maybe a standard term for that problem? Also, I don't see how solving Team AIGD's problem using maximum matching and greedy enumeration would give a reduction from maxflow. Just because you can solve something with maxflow doesn't mean it's P-complete as well.

Comment: @G.Bach: I see just now that we don't have designated source and sink here so what I said was mostly irrelevant. I still think that the problem is at least P-complete though, more likely even NP-complete. This is just my intuition, I don't have a proof.

Comment: Interesting to see that my question provoked such a discussion ... but in any case thanks for your thoughts :)

Comment: @NiklasB. What exactly do you think doesn't work with what I suggested?

Comment: @G.Bach: Ok so what I said before is also wrong. `all_simple_paths` indeed returns all simple paths between a given (source, target) pair, so I don't think how your algorithm would even begin to work in that scenario. So I guess we just talked about different problems the whole time.

Comment: @TeamAIGD: That basically means that some variation of your problem is interesting in an algorithmic sense to some extend. Don't get the illusion that this means your question is good. It's in fact lacking a lot of what constitutes a good question on SO, in particular research effort. There's not even a mention of what your own ideas on the subject are, so you should definitely work on that.

Comment: @NiklasB. You can use that method to get all paths of length k using the cutoff value k and iterating over all pairs of vertices as target and source; due to the symmetry of paths in undirected graphs, make sure not to call it on (t,s) again after you called it on (s,t) as source-target pair. Instead of reusing that though, it would be smarter to use the edge set and build the stuff yourself.

Comment: @G.Bach: What? Sure, you can do that but then you don't get the set of paths that OP considers. OP considers only paths from a specific source to a specific sink. Well whatever, this question is just bad and has much too little information to actually consider thinking about this too much

Comment: @NiklasB. I didn't realize until now that the task is to find minimally overlapping paths between two vertices (due to the complete lack of that being specified in the question). I had assumed that the end vertices of the paths are unimportant; that obviously makes what I said so far inapplicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a lot on your particular needs. There are a few options. Two built-in, and one that requires a bit more work, but might be faster.

If what you really want is to find two non-intersecting paths, then you can use a filtered graph - after finding one path, induce a subgraph with the intermediate nodes removed, and find the shortest path in that graph.

If you can't guarantee that the paths won't be non-intersecting, then you are back to brute-force. Since paths don't include cycles, and they are simple lists, finding the number of intersecting nodes is as simple as generating sets from the two paths and finding the length of their difference, which is pretty fast. Check all pairs and find the one with the fewest intersection.

Which of the above two is faster depends on your particular graph - is it sparse or dense? How many nodes are there? etc.

Since `all_simple_paths` is a generator, you can actually focus that algorithm somewhat. i.e. if you graph the first two paths, and they are completely non-intersecting, then you 
already have your minimal case and don't need to look at any more. There may be a lot of paths, but you can bound with an upper limit of how many to look at, or a threshold that is allowable (i.e. instead of absolutely 0, if these only have 1 in common, it's good enough, return it), or some other combination that uses both how many paths I've looked at and the current maximum to bound the calculation time.

If calculation time is really critical to your algorithm, also consider switching to igraph... networkx is MUCH easier to deal with, and usually performance is 'good enough', but for large brute force algorithms like this, igraph will probably be at least an order of magnitude faster.

One last possibility is to avoid using `all_simple_paths` at all, and use the bfs tree instead. I am not sure if `all_simple_paths` is BFS, it probably is, but that might give you a better selection of initial paths to look at with the second algorithm, not sure. E.G. if you know that your source node has multiple successors, you may get decent results by just forcing your starting two paths to start with two different successors instead of just from the initial node. Note that this can also bite you too - this greedy algorithm can lead you astray as well, unless your graph is already a good fit for it (which you may already know, or may not).

Comment: Thanks for these ideas. We basically ended up with a brute force like approach anyway. In short: we just compare any simple path with all other simple paths. If too many intersection nodes, then we skip that path. I guess it's fine in our case, the graph in question is not too big anyway.

Comment: You should create a set version of each path as you go then... it doesn't cost much, and if the first one fails, it will make checking the second path+ much cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a similarity or distance between two paths based on the number of edges that they share. Then apply a clustering algorithm to find n clusters, and pick one representative from each cluster, perhaps in a greedily fashion to minimise (in the case of similarities) edge weights between representatives.